# Why does the login method of Flask use 'GET'?

Tags: python, authentication, flask

I'm trying to learn more about Flask for a project, and I'm wondering if someone can explain to me why the sample code lists the methods 'GET' and 'POST', when it only ever tries to process a login if the request was 'POST'?

```
@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    error = None
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.form['username'] != app.config['USERNAME']:
            error = 'Invalid username'
        elif request.form['password'] != app.config['PASSWORD']:
            error = 'Invalid password'
        else:
            session['logged_in'] = True
            flash('You were logged in')
            return redirect(url_for('show_entries'))
    # Note that nowhere do we seem to care about 'GET'...
    return render_template('login.html', error=error)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

GET and POST methods are both handled by your function.

- When GET is used, the login form (`login.html`) is returned for the user to log in. This is the last line of the function.
- When POST is used, the form is validated using provided login/password. After that the user is either redirected to an other page (url for `show_entries`) or the login form is sent another time with the related error.

You should read '[When do you use POST and when do you use GET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46585/when-do-you-use-post-and-when-do-you-use-get)' for more details on why POST is used to process the login form and why GET is used to send it.

Answer (score 5):

`return render_template('login.html', error=error)` *is* the handler for `GET`.

Think about the logic:

1. if request.method == 'POST':

   1. Check Credentials, Set error method
   2. If no credential errors return the correct redirect
2. if there were errors in the POST section of code `render_template` gets those errors, otherwise it gets the `None` from the beginning of the method.  I assume that if error is `None` in `render_template` it probably just renders a plain ol' login form.

`Note: I've never used flask, but I understand python`